# Nested Async/Await Nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Cannot seem to figure out why this is not working for me. I have a parent function that performs an AWAIT on a child load process... the LOAD process in turn calls another AWAIT called LOADDATA... so basically like this:

```
module.exports = async function () {
    try {
       await load();

    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
        logger.error(ex);
    }
};

async function load() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        TableImport.findAll().then((tables) => {
           for (let table of tables) {
                await loadData(table.fileName, table.tableName);
            }
            resolve();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            reject(err);
        })
    })
};


async function loadData(location, tableName) {
    return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var currentFile = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../fdb/' + location);

        sequelize.query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + currentFile.replace('/', '//').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\') + "' INTO TABLE " + tableName + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'").then(function () {
            resolve(tableName);
        }).catch(function (ex) {
            reject();
        });
    });
};
```

the AWAIT in the LOAD fails stating:

await loadData(table.fileName, table.tableName);
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Clearly do not understand something about scope of the async!

Comment: There is no reason to do `return await ...`.  Just return the promise.  Also, should avoid the promise anti-pattern of wrapping a new promise around existing promises.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can only use `await` inside of an async function. If you have a non-async function nested inside of an async function, you can't use `await` in that function:

```
async function load() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        TableImport.findAll().then((tables) => {
           for (let table of tables) {
               await loadData(table.fileName, table.tableName);
```

You have a callback to the `.then` method above. This callback is not async. You could fix this by doing `async tables => {`.

However since `load` is async and `findAll` returns a promise, you don't need to use `.then`:

```
async function load() {
    const tables = await TableImport.findAll();
    for (let table of tables) {
        await loadData(table.fileName, table.tableName);
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what `loadData` does and if you have to load the tables in order, but you can also parallelize this:

```
const tables = await TableImport.findAll();
const loadPromises = tables.map(table => loadData(table.fileName, table.tableName));
await Promise.all(loadPromises);
```

- The `return await` is superfluous since you are already returning a promise. Just `return` will work.
- If you rewrite as I suggested, you don't need to use a Promise object since the methods you are working with return promises anyway.
- Your original function was resolving nothing, so this function works the same by returning nothing.
- Your original function was also propagating an error with `reject(err)`. This function does not handle an error internally so it will also propagate the error in the same way.

Your `loadData` function can also be rewritten and simplified quite a bit:

```
function loadData(location, tableName) {
    const currentFile = path.resolve(__dirname + '/../fdb/' + location);
    return sequelize.query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + currentFile.replace('/', '//').replace(/\\/g, '\\\\') + "' INTO TABLE " + tableName + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'");
};
```

- `loadData` doesn't need to be async since you don't use `await`. You are still returning a promise.
- You may want to add `.catch` since in your original code you didn't return an error. My code above will return the error caused by `.query`.
- You pass the table name in and you don't actually do anything with the return value, so I just removed the `.then` entirely.

Comment: OK right... made all those changes... i understand all of your comments but one question. The following does not work:

`async function load() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const tables = await TableImport.findAll() ;`

when i remove the `new Promise` it works... Can you explain why?

Comment: also this statement sort of threw me a little: `If you have a non-async function nested inside of an async function, you can't use await in that function:` but i made LOADDATA non-async and i can call that with await--it works....

Comment: I think you mean `function loadData { return aPromise; } ... async function load() { await loadData(); }`. The use of `async`/`await` has to do with scope. `loadData` is not in the `load` function scope. it's just being called in that scope.

Comment: kind of weird that LOADDDATA i know returns promise but when you add to promise array it runs the function on each row... not when the promise.all is called...

Comment: @user3597741 it's supposed to do that. It's just that it will wait for them all to finish before `Promise.all` resolves

Comment: is there a way to run the LOADDATA calls (approx: 130) in parallel? async.parallel???

Comment: They are running in parallel