# How to wait 'return' until 'dispatch' finish

Tags: reactjs

[React JS]How to wait 'return' until 'dispatch' finish in action creator?
I don't know how handle this ;(

i made some code. this is a part of action creator. But it return before dispatch finish. i want to dispatch finish before 'return'. help me please

```
export const Hello = param=> dispatch => {
  return postApi('/hello', param)
    .then(async res => {
      await dispatch(goHello(res));
       return true;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there really is no need to call return after dispatching an `action`. But if you'd like, you could use the `getState()` method to check that your action was processed before returning. `getState()` is the second argument of the redux-thunk function you are returning in your action-creator.

```
export const Hello = (param) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   postApi("/hello", param)
     .then((res) => {
         await dispatch(goHello(res))
    })
     .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err.response.data)
    })

   //check if reducer was updated
    const value = getState().keyOfReducerInStore <-- returns the state of your reducer, you can follow this up with whatever value you want to check
    if(value){
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. value show 'undefined'. ;( Any other idea of this problem?

Comment: Actually had a typo, should only return if value is true :)

Comment: Love you! I definitely got it!!

Comment: Awesome!! Welcome back to the boards @kiki. Glad this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await` on `postApi`. You can only use `await` directly inside of an `async` function. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928992/nested-async-await-nodejs?rq=1).

```
export const Hello = (param) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
   const res = await postApi("/hello", param); // <- code pauses here

   const res2 = await anotherPostApi("/helloagain", param); // <- will wait for above

   dispatch(goHello(res));

   // You can also wrap the await postApi in a try catch instead of using .catch


   const value = getState().keyOfReducerInStore <-- returns the state of your reducer, you can follow this up with whatever value you want to check
    if(value){
        return true
    }
}
```

Just remember. Promises can be `await`ed as long as they are directly inside of an `async` function. If you `console.log` a variable it'll show you if it is a `Promise`.